# Laptop freezes completely when watching videos

Tags: video

I am in hopes you all may be able to help me out. I am using Voyager GS which is based on Ubuntu 16.04. I have tried looking around their site to for forums or whatnot to be able to get help from them but I was not able to find it.

I am having an issue where if I watch videos in full screen my laptop completely locks up to the point I have to shut the computer down via holding the power button. This is most noticeable with on-line videos but also happens with VLC as well. I have seen a few threads on here and on other sites describing a similar issue but normally it is ONLY with on-line videos and has to do with flash. As this is not a flash only issue I have made my own thread. I think it may be a graphics driver issue as I have had similar freezes when playing torchlight 2 but I am not sure and I don't quite know how to troubleshoot that on Linux. Any help on what I should do would be greatly appreciated.

If it is of help I am using the HP 15-r011dx laptop and it has Intel HD Graphics http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c04272271

Comment: For me, pressing Ctrl+Alt+T for a terminal and using `killall chrome` or whatever application solves the problem, though not permanently.

Comment: Unfortunatly for me when it froze it would not accept any keyboard/mouse commands at all. I tried aurelio123's suggestion and so far it seems to work. Thanks for your suggestion tho :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using Oibaf's graphics-drivers PPA to update your drivers completely. This has solved some problems for me in the past when using Intel HD Graphics.

Be warned, this PPA contains drivers that are very bleeding edge, and may cause instability, as warned on the launchpad page. It will also send frequent driver updates almost daily. Although personally, I have never had any problems with it. For more info visit [the launchpad page](https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers?field.series_filter=xenial).

To do this, run the following commands:

```
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
    sudo apt update
    sudo apt upgrade
```

Comment: So far this seems to have done the trick. Thanks so much